# Can't launch Activity via Intent from AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm trying to launch an Activity from an AccessibilityService using an Intent with Extras.

Here's the Activity declaration in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.mydomain.accessApp.AccessibleLauncher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/INTENT_MY_SEARCH_QUERY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here's the code in the AccessibilityService:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, question);
                intent.setAction(getString(R.string.INTENT_MY_SEARCH_QUERY));
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Here is what my error catching code gets from the ActivityNotFoundException:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.mydomain.accessApp.AccessibleLauncher cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
```

Why am I receiving this error? I'm pulling the intent filter data from the strings.xml file (pulling the Accessibility Service intent filter data from there as well)

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent( this, nextActivity.class);`

Answer (score 1):

define the source and destination class while creating intent object..

take a look at this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```